# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to access a module in kaggle

Tags: python

I've a `model.py` file at this location:

```
../input/maskrcnn1/mrcnn/model.py
```

I want to import the `model` module and rename as `modellib`.

```
import os
import sys

mask_rcnn_path = os.path.abspath("../input/maskrcnn1")
sys.path.append(mask_rcnn_path)

from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
```

My code raised an error.

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/2870187516.py in <module>
      1 from mrcnn import utils
----> 2 import mrcnn.model as modellib
      3 from mrcnn import visualize

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mrcnn.model'
```

Comment: Does the directory `mrcnn` have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes, it is in `../input/maskrcnn1/mrcnn/__init__.py`